# How to send id value in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Like in url

```
Index.php/constructor/method/1
```

I want to get id.
I used

```
anchor("constructor/method/{$article->id}",'Edit');
```

This does not work, I get the following error :

> Using non-object as object

How can I retrieve the id value ?

Comment: What does the generated anchor look like?

Comment: You should try and include a bit more detail with the question.

Comment: What does `$article`  contain?

Answer (score 1):

If your 'id' is in the URI : index.php/constructor/method/1

You can get the value by using the URI library and segments.

ie.

uri : index.php/constructor/method/1

`$id = $this->uri->segment(3);`

*Feel free to check other functions for URI segment manipulation on [this page](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html) in docs.*

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where you get `$article->id` from because you have not pasted enough code.

Try on controller

```
$data['example'] = anchor("controller/method/" . $article->id,'Edit');
$this->load->view('example_view', $data);
```

Then on view

```
<?php echo $example_link;?>
```

You may need to set route

config/routes.php https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html#examples

```
$route['controller/method/(:any)'] = 'controller/method/$1';
```

config/autoload.php

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```